# Is it possible to turn my '08 Peugeot 207 into the facelift model?

Tags: peugeot, compatibility

I like the Peugeot 207 facelift model more than the original one. Is it possible to change the chassis elements (bumper, backlight etc.) to the newer ones? Are they completely compatible?